# How to query millions of JSON objects in multiple files with MariaDb CONNECT Engine without crash?

Tags: json, mariadb, bigdata, mariadb-connect-engine

Assume I have a collection of .json files in a folder, each of which represents exactly one book, i.e.

- Book 1 in folder/1.json
- Book 2 in folder/2.json
- …

The files are between only 6kb and 3mb in size each, but there are millions of them!

Now I do the following with MariaDb:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE books (
  isbn CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(256) NULL
) ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=JSON OPTION_LIST="PRETTY=2,JMODE=1,MAPPING=1" MULTIPLE=1 FILE_NAME="folder/*.json" READONLY=1;`

and then a simple query such as

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books;`

**This works fine if there are only a few files in the folder.** However, as soon there are even just a few thousands of them, it does not work anymore: The client crashes with `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` and the server logs are not really helpful (to me).

I guess this is a memory problem, but I do not understand why it happens: It does not seem necessary to load each file/book object into memory; the server could just go each file one-by-one, right?

**Things I tried without success**

- `PRETTY=0` instead of `PRETTY=2`
- `HUGE=1`
- `set global connect_work_size=999999999` (or so)
- `MAPPING=0`instead of `MAPPING=1`
- `max_allowed_packet=1024M` in my.ini

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**:
The files are just ordinary object JSON files, such as
`{"timestamp":1564002510168,"isbn":"9781081958077","author":"Mark Twain", "title": "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer: Annotated"}` (and some further attributes).

Comment: Can you show a example of the json?

Comment: few thousands files in one dir can be a reason for slowdown as well, searching a file can be slow then...

Comment: Ok, I have added an example. In fact, all 1.5 million files are in one directory. I know that this slows execution down, but speed is not a concern at the moment.  It just should not crash.